# Fragmented sentence

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, phrases, syntactic-analysis

> To the crowds that soon assembled to hear her preach, Dona Beatriz Kimpa Vita began to preach a radical new theology. There were saints in Kongo, she told, for was she, not proof?

I'm concerned about the last sentence of the above-mentioned extract of a paragraph - especially the second fragment: "for was she, not proof?". Is there a tag question? Is it well structured?

Comment: I can't make heads nor tails of "for was she" by itself. I think the last comma is a mistake. I think it should be "for was she not proof?" (she claimed to be proof that there were saints in Kongo)

Comment: It makes sense if you omit the comma between 'for' and 'was she'. In that case Dona Vita is saying "There are saints in Konga, and I am proof of that". She is asserting that she is a saint, and that this alleged fact is proof that there are saints in Konga. Men who wear glasses can marry pretty women, for am I not proof?

Comment: Usually, saints don't claim sainthood, but "she told" is off as a translation: *she said* or *she proclaimed* fits better.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin (point 2) I feel so too, but in the past couple of decades, a lot of new quotative verbs/structures have gained acceptance. (Here, it would be a quote-like structure. "There were saints in Kongo", she told ['them' licenses, of course]... She wished him "Happy Christmas" /// Q-LS: She wished him Happy Christmas. /  There were saints in Kongo, she told.